# Change display value in ext.form.combobox

Tags: extjs

Which property in Ext.form.Combobox is the field currently displayed in the ComboBox?

After a user selects something from the JsonStore and the value has been passed to combobox, the displayField is what shows up in the ComboBox's search field. I need to make a ComboBox where a user selects a certain object from JsonStore, but something totally unrelated is what displays in the ComboBox search field (this can't be done by changing any of the properties in the JsonStore record, because the string that is searched by the and the value that is passed in the end can not be different). I just need to override what is displayed in the combobox.

Answer (score 2):

What you may want to do is

- Have the displayField be the *"something totally unrelated is what displays in the ComboBox search field"*
- Then, override [doQuery](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/source/Combo.html#method-Ext.form.ComboBox-doQuery) to filter the store on `aThirdField` (or whatever)
- If you leave it at this, the dropdown will show displayFields as you type. When you select one item from the dropdown, displayField will be displayed in the search box (trigger field).
- This is all fine except that you want to change what is being displayed in the drop down.
- To fix this, configure the combobox's tpl property to display aThirdField or aFourthField or whatever you want to display in the dropdown.

In other words, the solution would be along the lines of -

- Always configure displayField to be the field that you want to see in the trigger field post item selection
- If you dont want to filter on displayField, override [doQuery](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/source/Combo.html#method-Ext.form.ComboBox-doQuery)
- If you dont want display anything other than displayField in the dropdown list, configure a [tpl](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox)

Reference - [Ext.form.ComboBox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox)

Comment: Thanks - That's great! I actually ended up doing something similar, but SO won't let me answer my own post for another 6 hours :/ I made a beforeSelect function that assigned displayField to the trigger field display value, and a beforeQuery function that assigned displayField to the jsonstore search value.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the displayed text different than the value.

```
    Ext.define('BasicStoreModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields : ['valueField', 'displayField']
    });

    var myStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        model: 'BasicStoreModel',
        data: [['value1','display1'], ['value2', 'display2']]
    });

items: [...
{
   fieldLabel: 'Label',
   xtype: 'combo',
   name: 'nameOfSelect',
   editable: false,
   store : myStore,
   displayField: 'displayField',
   valueField: 'valueField',
   queryMode: 'local',
   triggerAction: 'all',
}
```

The first two bits might seem like overkill, but I've wound up creating many SimpleStore instances which use BasicStoreModel. You should be able to extend JsonStore.

Comment: I actually need to make this work with 3 properties per record... the "valueField" which is the value of the chosen record (in my case a numeric code), a "displayField" which matches what is typed in by user and used to search the searchStore, and a third field which is what displays in the drop down and in the search box after an item is selected. I am able to make this third field appear in the drop down using a tpl, but is there a way to get this to display in search field after an item is selected, as well?

Comment: For now, what is shown when a user clicks on an option in the dropdown, what displays in the Search field is the "displayField" property. If possible, I would like the third property to display. Or, there is really only one drop-down choice where the displayField can NOT be shown to user after an option is selected, so a simple override of what is seen in the text box (without changing the selected value) would be okay.

Comment: Is there  way to set a "tpl" for a record in the search field itself, like you can do for a record in the drop down?